# Google App Engine + Google Cloud Storage + Sqlite3 + Django/Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

since it is not possible to access mysql remotely on GAE, without the google cloud sql, 
could I put a sqlite3 file on google cloud storage and access it through the GAE with django.db.backends.sqlite3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. SQLite requires native code libraries that aren't available on App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify files in Google Cloud Storage (see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview#open_object_write) for further details), I don't think it would be a good idea to even try it. Additionally, the overhead of downloading (probably) every time the whole sqlite file would make your app really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud SQL is meant for this, why don't you want to use it?

If you have every frontend instance load the DB file, you'll have a really hard time synchronizing them.  It just doesn't make sense.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Google Cloud SQL is too expensive. I need to pay $45 of usage only in June.

Comment: If your loads are low and you don't mind managing your own SQL, go with EC2 or Rackspace.